# Open host's browser from simulator?

Tags: react-native

On latest react-native 0.60 onwards, the default app will include a list of links at landing page as below

[image]

Now if this react-native project running on simulator and we click on one of the link, it will open up on our laptop instead of opening on browser from within the simulator. I'm wondering how it works so I took a look at `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Devtools/openURLInBrowser.js` and found below code

```js
'use strict';

const getDevServer = require('./getDevServer');

function openURLInBrowser(url: string) {
  // Made a console.log here and getDevServer().url = http://localhost:8081
  fetch(getDevServer().url + 'open-url', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({url}),
  });
}

module.exports = openURLInBrowser;
```

Despite having this source code, I still can't understand how can we use a `fetch` library to launch a url in host's browser? So far I've only use `fetch` to perform http request from some backend but apparently there's something more that `fetch` is providing?

Answer (score 0):

The Metro bundler is running on `8081`. `fetch` is performing a HTTP POST request to `http://localhost:8081/open-url`. Metro is able to handle this request and open up the browser accordingly.

An example Express web server may handle it like so:

```
app.post('/open-url', req => {
  const { url } = req.body;
  // Handle code to open URL
});
```

Comment: In other words if I wish to find out how it works, I should find my way to dig the implementation at metro instead?